# href=googlechrome:// or href=intent:// not work since android 7.1 in sign in

Tags: android, webview, href

I develop a captive portal to connect wifi on android.

here is the user process and my problem.

The user selects the public wifi network, it is then redirected to the 'sign in' of android and a web page is displayed for the user to be able to authenticate.

once the form validated I redirect the user to chrome for him posted a web page with the instructions of the place.

for redirected I use a http://portail"> or http://portail">

This method works well until Android 7.0 but more since android 7.1

I think this will come from a legal concern for the webview application?

help me

Comment: did you find an answer to that question ?

Comment: Hi, i don't have solution :-(, 
I did differently

Comment: can you please contact me and tell me how you figured that ? and how you open chrome from captive portal , or any browser for that matter?

ddor254@gmail.com